# Wrting out names with 6 cells between them

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write out names from another worksheet to another worksheet with 6 cells inbetween the names.

```
Sub names()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For j = 2 To 6054 Step 6
For i = 2 To 1010
Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(j, 12).Value = Worksheets("Worksheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

When i run the code it writes out the last name to every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want one loop,

With two each output cell cycles through the list of names till it reaches the last.

```
Sub names()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j=2
For i = 2 To 1010
    Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(j, 12).Value = Worksheets("Worksheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value
    j=j+6
Next i


End Sub
```